# LINQ expression in where clause with two collections

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

i have to make a query that have two ICollections in the where clause, but nothing that i tried worked here's what i tried:

```
    var segmentActivity = db.Activities.Where(x => x.Segment.Link == link).ToList();

    ICollection<Heading> hd = new List<Heading>();
    foreach(var activity in segmentActivity)
    {
        hd.Add(db.Headings.Where(x => x.ActivityId == activity.Id).First());
    }            

    ICollection<ProdutoSegmentoVM> produtos = new List<ProdutoSegmentoVM>();
    foreach(var produto in hd)
    {
                    //this is the where clause that i'm having problem v
        produtos.Add(db.Products.Where(x => hd.Contains(x.Headings.Where(h => h.Id == produto.Id).First())).Select(x => new ProdutoSegmentoVM()
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Description = x.Description,
            IsSpecification = (x.Specifications != null) ? true : false,
            Specification = (x.Specifications != null) ? x.Specifications.Select(s => new SpecItemVM() 
                            { 
                                Attribute = s.Attribute, 
                                Detail = s.SpecificationValues.Select(v => v.Detail).ToList()
                            })
                            .ToList() : null,
            Image = x.PrimaryImage.Name,
            SubTitle = x.Subtitle,
            Title = x.TitleMetadata
        })
        .First());
```

the exception thrown is: "Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

**EDIT:** Heading is an ICollection

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. In you WHERE clause you are trying to compare objects, and when LINQ translates your query to SQL, it cannot translate those objects. You have to select id's and compare those, or use the navigational properties.
2. You are still looping through collections manually, and that is not what LINQ is about. Select what you need, and use it in the next step.

Something like should work:

```
// Select activity-id's
var activityIds = db.Activities
    .Where(x => x.Segment.Link == link)
    .Select(x => x.Id);

// Use activity-id's to select heading-id's
var headingIds = db.Headings
    .Where(x => activityIds.Contains(x.ActivityId))
    .Select(x => x.Id);

var produtos = db.Products
    .Where(x => headingIds.Contains(x.Id))
    .Select(x => new {
        ...
    })
    .ToList();
```